# Remove single comma from an array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I have an array:

```
let array = ['john,1','mars,2','marry,3','  ,  '];
```

I want to filter the array in such a way that it should remove extra spaces and only a single comma (without text).

Expected Output:

```
let array = ['john,1','mars,2','marry,3']
```

I tried a few methods which removed all the commas.
Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nksg98te/4/)

Comment: `array.map(v => v.trim()).filter(v => v !== ",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = array.filter(el => {return  el.trim() !== ','})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['john,1','mars,2','marry,3'].map(x=>x.replace(',',''))
```

result: ['john1', 'mars2', 'marry3']